# Run time error ‘91’: object variable or with block variable not set

Tags: runtime-error

I am not a coder.

But I am working for a company that uses generators to produce spreadsheets and while running my weekly report, I received this error, then went to **debug** it and I am attaching what it is showing.

Can someone please help me figure this out?

Also, no there is no one in the company that knows how to fix this currently.

[image: img1]

I have tried probably nothing that would actually fix the coding issue.

Comment: I need help everyone LOL I have no idea how to fix this! I took a coding course in college and failed miserably